# MS Visual Studio - How to change default fields in new query template of TFS

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 professional version with Team Foundation client. During my day to day work, I need to run several queries on TFS. To make my query, I select `Team => New Query` menu. The query window is populated with 3 default fields. Every time, I need to remove these fields and add different fields.

[image]

Is there a way to customize `New Query` template?

I searched and found ways to create/edit custom template for work items etc., but no search returns any way to edit TFS Query template.

**Edit**

I am aware that I can create custom TFS queries, save them and later reuse them. Just want to know that just like work item template, if there is a way to edit query template.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not change that template. That is default behavior without any customization.

So you`ve supposed right way: you may create your own default blank work item query then use "save as" to create a new query.

Comment: It's a shame that this is not customizable. Any chance that this changed since?